# How to use an array result for evaluating

Tags: php, database, arrays

I want to use the array result in a calculation. Here is the code:

```
 $result1 = db_query("SELECT s.nid, s.stock FROM {uc_product_stock} s WHERE s.nid=$key ");

 $stock = array();
 foreach($result1 as $row){
         $stock[$row->nid] = $row->stock;
 }
 drupal_set_message("<pre>" . print_r($stock, true) . "</pre>");
```

It gives this as result:

```
Array
(
    [9] => 83
)
```

Now I want to use "83" as a variable to evaluate an equation i.e

```
$mul = $stock(i.e 83) * $price;
```

But as it("83") comes in an array it will give error. How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
$result1 = db_query("SELECT s.nid, s.stock FROM {uc_product_stock} s WHERE s.nid=$key ");

$stock = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

$mul = $stock["stock"] * $price;
```

It may be help you.

Comment: It gives nothing if i do: $stock[9]; dsm($stock[9]);. It gives an undefined variable error:stock.

Comment: will u kindly use $stock["9"]

Comment: ok do one thing . I am editing my answer. see that . think help you.

Comment: as $price=10 and $stock["stock"]=83 in my case so $mul should be 830. But it prints 0. why?

Comment: use your previous code and print $result1 then please give me the result what it is printing

Comment: now its working using foreach and caluclation inside foreach. Thanks for your time